# how to save a csv file to cloud object storage using project-lib?

Tags: r, ibm-cloud, object-storage, watson-studio, project-lib

I have a csv file that I have written to the notebook filesystem:

```
# read csv from object storage
df = read.csv2( ... )

# do some operations ...

# save new csv to notebook filesystem
file.remove('example.csv')
write.csv(df, file = "example.csv")
```

How can I copy this file to the project's cloud object storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
# import projectLib
library(projectLib)
project <- projectLib::Project$new(projectId="secret, projectToken="secret")

# get the file size:
csv.size = file.size('example.csv')

# read the file as a byte array
bytes.to.save = readBin('example.csv', 'raw', n = csv.size, size = NA_integer_, 
        signed = TRUE, endian = .Platform$endian)

# save the file to cloud object storage
project$save_data("example.csv", bytes.to.save, overwrite = TRUE)
```